# SourceTree git stash missing

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-stash

During move of git repository from one hard drive to another my GIT stash broke, or Sourcetree configuration is wrong. From that time my old stashes are not accessible and new one are visible only using GIT Terminal

I can apply stash on my working copy from terminal but it also should be visible in sourcetree sidebar. Any ideas what is wrong and how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: This is definitely a SourceTree bug, I've had the exact same issue with stashes created by SourceTree itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with missing stashes was caused by Commodo Antivirus. It was conflicting with whole git background processes. After uninstalling it whole problems with repository and CPU usage disapeared like with a touch of wand.

Comment: Interesting catch. More precise than my workaround. +1

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround would be to:

- apply, from the command line, the stash to your (clean) index
- stash, for SourceTree, the current index modification as a stash